# Convert .torrent file to magnet link/uri

Tags: javascript, torrent, magnet-uri

If found a lot of similar questions, but they were all about python or other programming languages that I don't really understand.

My question is really simple: How do I convert a .torrent file into a magnet link/URI? Assuming that functions like Base32Encode() or GetSha1Hash() already exist in the program. It doesn't really have to be in javascript, something like "You have to base32 encode the first 80 bytes of the file, multiply it by 5 and create an sha-1 hash form it would be enough.

Comment: Take a look at [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme). Hash the torrent as needed and add any extra information you want/have. The shortest magnet URI would be `magnet:?xt=urn:sha1:<base32 of SHA-1 hash>`

Comment: @GiantTree I tried to generate the hash etc from the .torrent file and I was not able to download anything with that magnet link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest magnet URI is just the hex-encoded info hash of the torrent:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:{info_hash}
```

To compute the info hash of a torrent, you need to SHA1-sum the `info` dict of the torrent file as a string.

Comment: The `info_hash` should be hex encoded, base32 encoding is legacy and should not be used any more.

Comment: And where is that info dict? How do I extract/generate that?